# Plot a function on a 2D surface

Tags: plotting

**My Question**

> How do you plot a function $f(x,y)=z$ on a 2D surface $g(x,y)=z$.

**A Simple Example**

```
f[x_, y_] := (x - 0.5)^2 + (y - 0.5)^2;
g[x_, y_] := y Sin[x y]
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
(* 2D surface I want to plot on *)
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image]
[image]

How can I plot the first on the second?

**Notes**

- If you have any questions or need clarification please ask.

Comment: `ColorFunction`?

Comment: Could you post a working example with `ColorFunction`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## `ColorFunction`

Consider:

```
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["RustTones"][f[x, y]/4.5]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Replace `"RustTones"` with your favorite value from `ColorData["Gradients"]` (I do not know how to mimic the original `DensityPlot` color scheme).

## The `DensityPlot` output + `PlotStyle`

Alternatively, use the original `DensityPlot` as a texture:

```
img = DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, Frame -> False, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None]
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Texture[img]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you the second option is really useful.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use a custom color function using your function `f` and the default color function for `DensityPlot` (which is `"M10DefaultDensityGradient"`) as follows:

```
minmax = Through[{NMinValue, NMaxValue}[{f[x, y], 0 <= x <= 2 && 0 <= y <= 2}, {x, y}]];

cF1 = ColorData["M10DefaultDensityGradient"][Rescale[f[#, #2], minmax]] &;

Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, ColorFunction -> cF1,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Lighting -> "Ambient", ViewPoint -> {1.5, -.5, 3}]
```

[image]

Use a different gradient color scheme, say `"CMYKColors"`, instead of `"M10DefaultDensityGradient"` to get:

[image]