# Plot a `RegionPlot` on a 2D Surface

Tags: plotting

This is a quick follow up to my other [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/215884/44420) which I thought was different enough to warrant a separate post.

**My Question**

> How do you plot a region (such as $f(x,y)>z$) on a 2D surface $g(x,y)=z$ and change the color of the region?

**A Simple Example**

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x] + Sin[y];
g[x_, y_] := y x Sin[x y];
img = RegionPlot[3/2 > f[x, y] > 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
  Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Black]
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Texture[img]}]
```

[image]
[image]

So I have figured out how to overlay the region plot on the surface, but the only color the region appears is black. This is in spite that I specified the `RegionPlot` to be `Orange`. How can I change the region plot on the surface to anything but black.

**Notes**

- If you have any questions or need clarification please ask.
- Again this is a quick follow up on my previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/215884/44420).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### MeshFunctions + MeshShading

```
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2},
 MeshFunctions -> {f[#, #2] &}, 
 Mesh -> {{1, 3/2}}, 
 MeshShading -> {White, Orange}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

#### BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics

Get a *single* polygon from `img` using [`BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics.html) and use it as the texture:

```
img2 = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[img, MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> Orange, 1 -> Black}, 
   ImagePadding -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> 0];

Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Texture[img2], 
 Mesh -> None, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

#### Plot3D + RegionFunction

```
Show[Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> None], 
 Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Black, Mesh -> None, RegionFunction -> (1 < f[#, #2] < 3/2 &)]]
```

[image]

#### ImageMultiply

Minimal change in OP's code that gives the desired result is to use `Texture[ImageMultiply[img, White]]` instead of `Texture[img]`:

```
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[ImageMultiply[img, White]],
 Mesh -> None, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

#### Post-process RegionPlot output into 3D polygons:

You can use `PlotStyle -> None` in `Plot3D` and *lift* the 2D region plot surface to 3D replacing coordinate `{x,y}` with `{x,y, g[x,y]}`:

```
Show[Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> None], 
 Graphics3D[Cases[img, GraphicsComplex[a_, b__] :> 
    GraphicsComplex[{##, g[##]} & @@@ a, b]]], Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is an interesting approach, but can you do it with no meshes?

Comment: @AzJ, please see the update.

Comment: @kglr As you will soon pass me in *reputation* I am happy to see that you are writing answers I would be proud to call my own. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you for the kind words. A lot of my answers are in fact based on what i have learned from yours. Re passing you in reps, that sounds like you intend to keep the target fixed for a while longer (which, I hope, is not the case btw :).

Answer (score 2):

You may also try Piecewise:
 Something similar to this for defining Colorfunction of separate regions.

```
    colfn = Piecewise[{{Red, 3/2 > f[#, #2] > 1}, {White, True}}] &

    Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
    PlotPoints -> 200, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> colfn, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> None]
```

Also, check Exclusions in the plot options.